# Homeomorphism and quotient map

Tags: general-topology

What is the difference btw homeomorphism and quotient map? If quotient map has injectivity can we say it is homeomorphism?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by 'quotient map'?

Comment: My bad. For topological spaces X and Y and surjective map p: X->Y, p is a quotient map provided a subset U of Y is open in Y iff p^-1(U) is open in X.

Comment: Yes, according to this definition, it is immediate that injective quotient maps are the same as homeomorphisms. And the difference is that quotient maps need not be injective..

Answer (score 1):

Yes a quotient map $q:X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism iff $q$ is injective. This is almost immediate from the definitions.

A typical quotient map will have distinct points that are "glued together", so $q(x)=q(x')$ for some $x \neq x'$, an older name for quotient map is "identification map", e.g.

The dual statement is that an embedding $f: X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism iff $f$ is surjective.